# Copy a 2-D array to another array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array

I have a statement like this in Ruby:

```
@mastertest = connection.execute("select code_ver from mastertest")
```

So now I want to make a copy of this 2-D array, because if I do something like `@temp = @mastertest`, it makes changes to `@mastertest` when I make any changes to `@temp`.

I tried using the following:

```
@temp = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(@mastertest))
```

But this gives me an error saying `"no marshal_dump is defined for class Mysql2::Result"`. So I am assuming that the `@mastertest` is of some other type than a 2-D array.

Can someone help me how to make a copy of this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using the following:

```
@new_array = Array.new
@mastertest.each { |r| @new_array.push(r[0]) }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to work here: (dup or clone isn't fully deep copy, only Marshal does).

1. Use Object#dup or clone. Try `@temp = @mastertest.dup`. I don't know the format of Mysql2::Result, so this way may fail when it is like a "2-D array", which you have to dup each element in the Enumerable-mixed class. The `dup` method just calls `initialize_copy` for that class. If there is anything not POD(plain-old-data) in an array-like object, it will only make a shallow copy for it.
2. Write your monkey patch for `Mysql2::Result` with two methods: `marshal_dump` and `marshal_load`. This will make it respond to `Marshal.dump`. See the doc [about Marshal here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@temp = @mastertest.clone
```

Now changes to @temp will not affect the @mastertest

Comment: This will not work for something like 2-D array. For example, `a = [[1,2]]   b = a.dup    a[0] << 3   puts b`.